# Can I somehow adapt IMAP connections to Exchange server connections?

Tags: email, proxy, exchange, imap, email-client

At work, they have an MS Exchange Server which I have no control over. It doesn't have IMAP connection support configured, nor Outlook Web Access (as far as I can tell). I read that Evolution supports MS Exchange Server, but I don't like it, especially not on Windows. I would like to be able to use any mail client... and for this reason, I need to do some kind of protocol adaptation between IMAP and Exchange. Is there a way to effect this with some simple scripting (at least for basic functionality), or is some custom utility/facade/proxy/etc. necessary?

Comment: @mdpc: Restated the question to be more on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The following requires Outlook Web Access (OWA).

Very late response I know, this is for anyone Googling from here on.

I believe that DavMail is what you want. http://davmail.sourceforge.net/

> Ever wanted to get rid of Outlook ? DavMail is a POP/IMAP/SMTP/Caldav/Carddav/LDAP exchange gateway allowing users to use any mail/calendar client (e.g. Thunderbird with Lightning or Apple iCal) with an Exchange server, even from the internet or behind a firewall through Outlook Web Access. DavMail now includes an LDAP gateway to Exchange global address book and user personal contacts to allow recipient address completion in mail compose window and full calendar support with attendees free/busy display.
>
> DavMail also supports the CardDav protocol to sync address books. This new feature is sponsored by French Defense / DGA through project Trustedbird

Comment: Looks like DavMail requires Outlook Web Access to be enabled. It isn't. So - this doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, well that sucks :-( Sorry I couldn't help :-(